# Convert a `not in` sub query to a `join`

Tags: postgresql, join

Normally converting a sub query to a join is relatively straightforward, but this case has been stumping me. Given

```
CREATE TABLE pages(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   name           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   category_id            INT     NOT NULL,
   some_setting        CHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('a', 10, 'lorem');
INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('b', 10, 'lorem');
INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('invalid', 10, 'true');


INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('a', 20, 'lorem');
INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('b', 20, 'lorem');
INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('invalid', 20, 'false');


INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('a', 30, 'lorem');
INSERT INTO pages (name, category_id, some_setting) VALUES ('b', 30, 'lorem');
```

I can query for

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE category_id not in (SELECT category_id FROM pages WHERE name = 'invalid' AND some_setting = 'true')
```

But due to the the fact that the `page[name=special]` doesn't need to exist I can't easily convert this to a join. Anybody any idea? Here is a link to an SQLFiddle, but it refuses to save the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c4ca7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this having

```
select pg1.*
from pages pg1 
      left join pages pg2 on pg1.category_id = pg2.category_id
group by pg1.id
having
    ARRAY['invalid', 'true']::text != ALL (ARRAY_AGG(array[pg2.name, pg2.some_setting]::text))
order by pg1.id  
;
```

Why you do not what use `in` statement? I know that `not in` not use index. But having not use it too.

Comment: Performance was indeed the reason I was hoping to switch to a simpler join... looking at that construction you just wrote I fear it actually is not possible. Guess I will need to refactor my database then and make sure there always is an `invalid` record. :( Thanks!